# Random Number Generator for X,Y Coordinates

Tags: swift, random, numbers, generator

I was writing code today and I stumbled across a problem with my random number generator. I am trying to make a generator much like the one in Fruit Ninja, I am also writing in swift. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var rand_x = arc4random() 
var rand_y = arc4random()
node!.position = CGPoint(x: rand_x, y: rand_y)
```

My problem is I am getting the error:

> Cannot find an initializer for type 'CGPoint' that accepts an argument list of type '(x: UInt32, y: UInt32)'

Any tips how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- You will likely need to cap the maximum value of your position at some value, e.g. the width/height of the screen
- arc4random returns a UInt32, and CGPoint's initializer takes CGFloats. You'll need to translate your UInt32s to CGFloats

This would look like:

```
var rand_x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(maxXValue)) // maxXValue is a variable with your maximum possible x value
var rand_y = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(maxYValue)) // maxYValue is a variable with your maximum possible y value
node!.position = CGPoint(x: rand_x, y: rand_y)
```

Answer (score 1):

`arc4random()` function return type is `UInt32`, but `CGPoint` doesn't have an initializer where `x` & `y` are `UInt32`.

Either you can cast `rand_x` and `rand_y` to a compatible type for the initializer (such as `Int` or `CGFloat`) like this :

```
var rand_x = arc4random()
var rand_y = arc4random()
let point = CGPoint(x: Int(rand_x), y: Int(rand_y))
```

Either you can make an extension to `CGPoint` introducing a `UInt32` initializer :

```
extension CGPoint {
    init(x: UInt32, y: UInt32) {
        self.x = CGFloat(x)
        self.y = CGFloat(y)
    }
}
```

Please note that `CGPoint` is a struct containing two members `x` and `y` of type `CGFloat` (that's why I'm casting in `CGFloat` in my initializer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `rand_x` and `rand_y` to `CGFloat`s first.

```
node!.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(rand_x), y: CGFloat(rand_y))
```

Also take a look at `arc4random_uniform`